# Applicative Functors - function not mapping

Tags: haskell

Why this works:

`(+) <$> (*2) <*> (*2) $ 2`

But this one doesn't?

`(+) <$> (*2) <*> (*2) <*> (*2) $ 2` 
(error is: cannot construct the infinite type)

Yet this one does:

`(\x y z -> x + y + z) <$> (*2) <*> (*2) <*> (*2) $ 2`

Sorry if these are trivial questions, I'm in the journey of learning Haskell and want to make sure I understand it fully before moving on to the next topics.

Comment: This has nothing in particular to do with applicative functors. It fails for the same reason `(+) 2 3 4` fails.

Comment: BTW, I strongly recommend that for any understanding issue regarding applicatives (or monads) you avoid the function applicative, because it makes it very easy to mix up the functions that are mapped with those that are the “containers” which you map them over. `Maybe` or `[]` are much less confusing examples. I.e., consider something like `(+) <$> [2] <*> [4,5]` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(+)` is the same as `(\x y -> x + y)`, or if you had a really weird `Num` instance in scope `(\x y z -> (x + y) z)`, which is not the same as `(\x y z -> x + y + z)`. The simple explanation is that `(+)` takes two arguments, and in your non-working snippet, you're trying to pass it three. Your third snippet works because you're using two `+`s instead of just one. Consider that `(+) 4 4` and `(+) ((+) 4 4) 4` are both valid, but that `(+) 4 4 4` is not.

Answer (score 4):

The type of `(+)` is `Int -> Int -> Int` (actually it is more general, but I will use the concrete type `Int` for this example). So, it is a function that takes two integers as input.

The type of `(\x y z -> x + y + z)` is `Int -> Int -> Int -> Int`. So, it is a function that takes three integers as input.

These two functions are not interchangeable, because the types are not the same.

Perhaps your confusion stems from the unclear error message. If you actually write out the concrete type of `(+)` like this:

```
ghci> ((+) :: Int -> Int -> Int) <$> (* 2) <*> (* 2 ) <*> (* 2) $ 2
```

Then you get a nicer error message:

```
<interactive>:7:1: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Int' with `Int -> t'
      Expected type: Int -> Int -> t
        Actual type: Int -> Int
    * Possible cause: `(<*>)' is applied to too many arguments
      ...
    * Relevant bindings include it :: t (bound at <interactive>:7:1)
```

Still not very clear, but at least it mentions that the number of arguments is off.

Comment: Hm, how impractical would it be to make `(+)` variadic, à la `printf` trick?

Comment: You can make a variadic summation function, but you can't really call it `+`, because that is a binary operator. Also, variadic functions don't play very nicely with type inference and error messages. You can instead do `fmap sum (sequence [(* 2), (* 2), (* 2)]) 2`, but that quickly becomes hard to understand too. Perhaps the simplest and most readable option is just to write `(\x -> sum [x * 2, x * 2, x * 2]) 2`.